# Issues with MySQL query construction

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query in MySQL to do the following:

"If there are no students in the department without assigned advisors, find the
existing instructor with the most advisees and reassign one of their advisees to the new
instructor."

The table definitions are :

```
Advisor(i_id, s_id) - i_id, s_id is the primary key.
Instructor(i_id, name, dept_name, salary) - i-id is the primary key.
Student(s_id, name, dept_name, tot_cred) - s_id is the primary key.
```

I have written the following query, which is incomplete, but I am unsure how to proceed:

```
SELECT MAX(counted) 
(SELECT i_id, COUNT(s_id) AS counted
 FROM Advisor
 GROUP BY i_id) ;
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Are these the only tables? Where is the student table, surely s_id is not the advisor primary key (assuming s_id = student id)

Comment: I have provided the edit with the student table info ..... and yes s_id = student id.

Comment: You would normally use ORDER BY LIMIT 1 for this - unless your concerned about ties - probably not in this instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no students in the department without assigned advisors:

```
SELECT Student.s_id from Student
WHERE s_id NOT IN ((SELECT DISTINCT(s_id) from Advisor) AS Assigned)
```

find the existing instructor with the most advisees

```
SELECT MAX(value), i_id
FROM
(SELECT i_id, COUNT(*) as value
FROM Advisor
GROUP BY i_id) AS counted)
```

reassign one of their advisees to the new instructor

```
Done Manually
```

Haven't tested this, there may be some syntax errors here